# DataType Versus Required data annotation, when using Templated Helpers and non Templated Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

i have defined the following data annotations for my model object:-

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Book Name is required !!!")]
public string BookName { get; set; }
```

i am rendering the model at the view using the following:-

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookName)
```

but when i changed the above to the following:-

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BookName)
```

then only the `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Book Name is required !!!")]`was working . so i thought that both the Required and the DataType would not work if i use the Non Templated helper (TextAreaFor),, so why the [Required] worked in this case while the DataType did not?.
BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MultileneText attribute wont work because of using `TextBoxFor` helper. If you were use `EditorFor` helper, that helper renders property as an textarea html input. But you dont give any change to render textarea to that helper by using `TextBoxFor` helper which renders as `<input type='text'/>`.

So multiline attribute couldnt assign to input anymore.